# trigger.io toolkit reload tab fails to load

Tags: reload, trigger.io

The reload tab has been failing to load since at least sometime last night (12+ hours). I've tried the "Clean app" option, but otherwise I'm not sure what to do. Here's the error that eventually comes back to the top of the screen:

```
Error in remote call to reload.verify_config: GET to reload/buildevents/ce8b0e4afeac11e1bdde12313d1adcbe failed: <Response [504]> Details Close
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
 File "C:\Users\bholub\AppData\Local\Trigger Toolkit\build-tools\forge\async.py", line 96, in run
    result = self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "C:\Users\bholub\AppData\Local\Trigger Toolkit\trigger\api\reload.py", line 81, in verify_config
    buildevents = forge_tool.singleton.remote.buildevents(path)['buildevents']   File "C:\Users\bholub\AppData\Local\Trigger Toolkit\build-tools\forge\remote.py", line 627, in buildevents
    resp = self._api_get(url)   File "C:\Users\bholub\AppData\Local\Trigger Toolkit\build-tools\forge\remote.py", line 223, in _api_get
    _check_api_response_for_error(url, 'GET', resp)   File "C:\Users\bholub\AppData\Local\Trigger Toolkit\build-tools\forge\remote.py", line 94, in
_check_api_response_for_error
    raise RequestError(resp, msg) RequestError: GET to reload/buildevents/ce8b0e4afeac11e1bdde12313d1adcbe failed: <Response [504]>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was caused by some un-optimised app server code on the Trigger.io side: your particular usage was especially awkward for our code hence the 504s.

I pushed a fix for it yesterday: everyone should see a snappier Reload tab now!